# Como salvar todos os resultados de dicionario em um arquivo JSON?

Tags: python

Estou filtrando um arquivo JSON e transformando na formatação COCO. Preciso salvar todos os resultados em um JSON só, mas não estou conseguindo. Tentei colocar os resultados em uma lista, porem ou só salva o primeiro resultado ou salva 121 vezes o ultimo resultado. Tentei colocar em outro dicionário, tambem sem sucesso. Eu consigo jogar os resoltados direto no arquivo, porem entre o resoltado e outro fica faltando a vírgula.

Esse é meu primeiro post aqui na plataforma, me dá uma ajudinha aí!

```
import json

coco_format = {}
images = {}
categories = {}
annotations = {}
bbox = {}
area = {}
list_data = []

def format_to_coco(json_file_path):

with open(json_file_path, 'r') as file:
    contents = json.loads(file.read())

for index_annotation in range(len(contents)):
    # Variavél que possibilita checar se houve skip na anotação
    result = contents[index_annotation]['annotations'][0]['was_cancelled']

    # Checando se skip na anotação
    if result == False:

        # O valor da largura da imagem
        width_from_json = contents[index_annotation]["annotations"][0]["result"][0]["original_width"]

        # Extraindo a altura da imagem do arquivo JSON
        height_from_json = contents[index_annotation]["annotations"][0]["result"][0]["original_height"]

        # id da imagem
        image_id = contents[index_annotation]["id"]

        # nome do arquivo imagem
        image_json_name = contents[index_annotation]["data"]['image'].split('/')[-1]

        # Categoria
        category = contents[index_annotation]['annotations'][0]['result'][0]['value']['polygonlabels'][0]

        # Pontos da segmentação do arquivo JSON
        polygon_segmentation_points = contents[index_annotation]["annotations"][0]["result"][0]["value"]["points"]

        # Conversão das coordenadas x e y do JSON de porcentagem para pixel
        pixels_coordenates = convert_coordinate_percent_to_pixels(polygon_segmentation_points, width_from_json, height_from_json)

        # Organizando as coordenadas x e y para uma lista  
        organized_pixels_coordenates = organizing_coordenates(pixels_coordenates)

        # Coordenadas do bbox
        total_area_bbox = total_area_bounding_box(pixels_coordenates)

        # Calculo da área de poligono irregular
        #total_area_polygon = irregular_polygon_calculation(pixels_coordenates)

        # Formatando para COCO e salvando em JSON
        images["width"] = width_from_json
        images["height"] = height_from_json
        images["id"] = image_id
        images["file_name"] = image_json_name

        categories["id"] = index_annotation
        categories["name"] = category

        annotations["id"] = index_annotation
        annotations["image_id"] = image_id
        annotations["category_id"] = category
        annotations["segmentation"] = organized_pixels_coordenates
        annotations["bbox"] = total_area_bbox[0][0:-1]
        annotations["area"] = total_area_bbox[0][-1]
        #annotations["area"] = total_area_polygon


        coco_format["images"] = images
        coco_format["categories"] = categories
        coco_format["annotations"] = annotations

        data = {"imagens": images, "categories": categories, "annotations": annotations}

        saving_json(data)

def saving_json(list_data):
with open(f"coco_file.json", "a") as out_file:
            json.dump(list_data, out_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

format_to_coco('project-22-at-2022-12-05-16-23-de7b066b.json')
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava formatando para COCO da forma incorreta. O correto é acrescentar o dicionário dentro de uma lista e não o contrário. Com o resultados das listas eu crio um dicionário final formatado corretamente, conforme pode ser analisado no código.

```
import json

coco_format = {}
images = []
categories = []
annotations = []
bbox = []
area = []

def format_to_coco(json_file_path):
    
    with open(json_file_path, 'r') as file:
        contents = json.loads(file.read())

    for index_annotation in range(len(contents)):
        # Variavél que possibilita checar se houve skip na anotação
        result = contents[index_annotation]['annotations'][0]['was_cancelled']

        # Checando se skip na anotação
        if result == False:

            # O valor da largura da imagem
            width_from_json = contents[index_annotation]["annotations"][0]["result"][0]["original_width"]

            # Extraindo a altura da imagem do arquivo JSON
            height_from_json = contents[index_annotation]["annotations"][0]["result"][0]["original_height"]

            # id da imagem
            image_id = contents[index_annotation]["id"]

            # nome do arquivo imagem
            image_json_name = contents[index_annotation]["data"]['image'].split('/')[-1]

            # Categoria
            category = contents[index_annotation]['annotations'][0]['result'][0]['value']['polygonlabels'][0]

            # Pontos da segmentação do arquivo JSON
            polygon_segmentation_points = contents[index_annotation]["annotations"][0]["result"][0]["value"]["points"]

            # Conversão das coordenadas x e y do JSON de porcentagem para pixel
            pixels_coordenates = convert_coordinate_percent_to_pixels(polygon_segmentation_points, width_from_json, height_from_json)

            # Organizando as coordenadas x e y para uma lista  
            organized_pixels_coordenates = organizing_coordenates(pixels_coordenates)

            # Coordenadas do bbox
            total_area_bbox = total_area_bounding_box(pixels_coordenates)

            # Calculo da área de poligono irregular
            #total_area_polygon = irregular_polygon_calculation(pixels_coordenates)

            # Formatando para COCO e salvando em JSON
            images.append(
                {
                    "width": width_from_json, "height": height_from_json, "id": image_id, "file_name": image_json_name
                }
            )

            categories.append({"id": index_annotation, "name": category})

            annotations.append(
                {
                    "id": index_annotation,
                    "image_id": image_id,
                    "category_id": category,
                    "segmentation": organized_pixels_coordenates,
                    "bbox": total_area_bbox[0][0:-1],
                    "area": total_area_bbox[0][-1]
                }
            )

            data = {"imagens": images, "categories": categories, "annotations": annotations}

        saving_json(data)

def saving_json(list_data):

    with open(f"json_files/coco_file.json", "w") as out_file:
                json.dump(list_data, out_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode salvar o dicionário Python em arquivos JSON usando um módulo integrado json. Precisamos usar o método json.dump() para fazer isso.

Exemplo:

```
importar json

# dicionario desejado
sampleDict = { "nome": "Bruno", "Nota": 5 }
with open("student.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(developer, write_file, indent=4)
```

Use o parâmetro indent para identar seu arquivo JSON. Você também pode usar sort_keys para classificar as chaves do dicionário enquanto as escreve no arquivo JSON.

Referencias: https://pynative.com/python-json-dumps-and-dump-for-json-encoding/

Comment: Valeu mano, eu consegui achar o problema e resolver.